# Issues scraping a dynamic table displaying available and booked time slots

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape the following website:https://padelbox.de/koeln-weiden/padelplatz-buchen. I want to scrape the planning tool every day and see what slots are booked and which are not. However, using the code below an error code suggesting the values are not found. Can anyone help me with this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import requests
import time

website = 'https://padelbox.de/koeln-weiden/padelplatz-buchen'
path = '/Users/joeplamers/Downloads/chromedriver_mac_arm64/chromedriver'

# Initialize the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
# Open the website
driver.get(website)

#close the cookie pop-up and maximize window
all_matches_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="_brlbs-btn _brlbs-btn-accept-    all _brlbs-cursor"]')
all_matches_button.click()
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[data-state="booked"]')))
booked_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[data-state="booked"]')
print(booked_elements)


#Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired elements are within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be visible*.
- You can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  ```
  driver.get("https://padelbox.de/koeln-weiden/padelplatz-buchen")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a._brlbs-btn-accept-all"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.eversports.de/widget']")))
  print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td[data-state='booked'][data-date]")))))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  318
  ```

---

### Update

Here's the complete code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://padelbox.de/koeln-weiden/padelplatz-buchen")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a._brlbs-btn-accept-all"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.eversports.de/widget']")))
print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td[data-state='booked'][data-date]")))))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Could you share the complete code? I cannot seem to make it work. Still get an error  that the elements do not exist.